# hyperledger fabric byfn.sh up failed with script scripts.sh not found

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to build the first-network of hyperledger-fabric in WSL

I get the simple code from git then download the platform-specific binaries follow the guide in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#start-the-network . But when I run the command  ./byfn.sh  up , the error occurred

```
root@LENOVO-PC:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network# ./byfn.sh up
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.3
=================== WARNING ===================


    > Local fabric binaries and Docker images are out of sync. This may
    > cause problems.

Starting peer1.org1.example.com ... done                                                                                                                     Starting peer1.org2.example.com ... done                                                                                                                     Starting peer0.org2.example.com ... done                                                                                                                     Starting orderer.example.com    ... done                                                                                                                     Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... done                                                                                                                     cli is up-to-date
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                      NAMES
95f095123a0d        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                                         cli
adb4c6d2d4ce        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
d9c4813c8d22        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
026b1d3e85aa        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
add0499d007b        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           5 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp     orderer.example.com
b15463852d31        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

And i find the wrong command `docker exec cli scripts/script.sh $CHANNEL_NAME $CLI_DELAY $LANGUAGE $CLI_TIMEOUT $VERBOSE $NO_CHAINCODE` in byfn.sh.
then I enter the folder `scripts` , change the command to `docker exec cli script.sh $CHANNEL_NAME $CLI_DELAY $LANGUAGE $CLI_TIMEOUT $VERBOSE $NO_CHAINCODE`and execute it.
Get the output

```
root@LENOVO-PC:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/scripts# docker exec cli script.sh $CHANNEL_NAME $CLI_DELAY $LANGUAGE $CLI_TIMEOU
T $VERBOSE $NO_CHAINCODE
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"script.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Is there something wrong about the environment variable of docker caused by WSL?

Comment: Try to look where the script resides inside the container, by doing: `docker exec -it cli /bin/bash`

Comment: here is the output :`/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#`

Comment: I didn't find the script in the container, there is nothing in ./scripts `root@LENOVO-PC:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/scripts# docker exec -it cli /bin/bash
root@95f095123a0d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# ls
                channel-artifacts  crypto  scripts
root@95f095123a0d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# cd scripts/
root@95f095123a0d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts# ls
root@95f095123a0d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts#`

Comment: Is the script which should exist in container the copy of script in project folder(file path:`~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/scripts/script`)

Comment: this is weird.... do you see the script outside of the container?

Comment: How to find the script outside the container? I don't know much about it. And It seems there is something wrong with my environment variables, I  try to fix it.

Comment: Asuka, try to synchronize the fabric samples folder with the latest version, you see the warning: "Local fabric binaries and Docker images are out of sync. This may
    > cause problems."

Comment: also you can ask in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions for help

Comment: Are you trying to use WSL and Docker for Windows?  Need to know a bit more about your environment.

Comment: yes i use WSL and docker for windows. What else do you want to know？

Comment: Should the project be locate in a specified folder?

Comment: first of all, install fabric-samples separately not inside the github. folder. it should be inside the src/fabric-samples. secondly, ur fabric-samples folder is located inside the  go folder, it shouldn't be like that. Go is the folder for golang software, even ur Go projects should be in separate folder, as an example: "GoProjects". So in ur case it shoud be as following: "GoProjects/src/fabric-samples". then lastly, before starting the network "./byfn.sh up" u should first generate it as following: "./byfn.sh generate"

Comment: I move the project to /usr/src/fabric-samples,and when generating it by `./byfn.sh generate` , the output is of five parts which are`Generate certificates using cryptogen tool` `Generating Orderer Genesis block` `Generating channel configuration transaction 'channel.tx' `  `Generating anchor peer update for Org1MSP` `Generating anchor peer update for Org2MSP `. Then I start the network by "./byfn.sh up", there is stiil the error `container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown`